# Finding IDs that have been consistently failing to meet target

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with data columns including ID, Domain, Target, and Dates (The table seen below). I am currently performing analysis on it and having trouble in finding which IDs have been failing consistently to meet the target.

I found an average of all my dates columns and basically compared it manually with my target value. I am not too sure if its the right way of doing it.

```
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 

# Create sample dataframe
 raw_data = {'ID': ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'], 
'Domain': ['Finance', 'IT', 'IT', 'Finance'], 
'Target': [1, 2, 3, >1], 
"1/01":[0.9, 1.1, 2.1, 1],
"1/02":[0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.9], 
"1/03":[1, 1, 0.5, 1.1], 
"1/04":[0.7, 0.7, 0.1, 1],
"1/05":[0.7, 0.7, 0.1, 1], 
"1/06":[0.9, 1.1, 2.1, 1]}


 df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['ID', 'Domain', 'Target', '1/01', 
'1/02','1/03', '1/04','1/05', '1/06'])

# Create avg of 1/01 to 1/06 columns
df["avg"]=df.iloc[:,3:9].mean(axis=1)

# Select required columns/rows
 print (df[(df.Domain == 'Finance')].loc[:, 
 ['ID','Domain','Target','avg']])
```

The main question that I must answer is

1) Which ID has been failing consistently?

2) Which I have been meeting consistently, beating the target very comfortably?

Comment: 'Target': [1, 2, 3, >1]  Please explain >1

Comment: Hi, yes so basically that '>1' means that any value for the date columns greater than 1 is considered as meeting target for that ID.

Comment: The question is *how could you use that in a list?* My Python chokes on it!

Comment: And is you question about the Python way to solve the problem, or what algo you should use? For the latter part, if you do not know what you want to obtain, we do not either...

Comment: Yes so basically I want to know how i can obtain answer to my two questions that are listed above using code.. Thats where i am struggling

Comment: Technically speaking we dont need to find the average of all the dates columns. I was just told that i do not need to find average of all columns. Infact, I first have to compare all the dates value against my target value for the ID.

Comment: Now the problem I am facing here is that i am having trouble comparing the target value with multiple date values (multiple date columns) in code way. Thats what i want to know, That how can i compare my target value against multiple dates column for that ID